# Upstart won't reload it's configuration

Tags: linux, redhat, upstart

I have a service I'm trying to write an upstart script for and it's not going too well. At some point, I decided I needed a fresh start and removed the upstart configuration file.

```
stop myservice
rm -f /etc/init/myservice.conf
initctl reload-configuration
```

However, upstart still shows my service in the list as "stopped/killed".

```
initctl list
status myservice
```

How is this possible and how can I get rid of my service for good without restarting the machine? For reference, `initctl --version` shows 0.6.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, restarting fixed the problem in the long run. Though I wish I didn't have to wait two weeks or so before being able to get rid of that stale entry.